# How to determine at compile time if two vectors have the same length in C++?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, typing, compile-time

Let's say I have the following code:

```cpp
// A function that modifies the values in the 2 vectors
// But it needs the 2 vectors to have the same length
void compute(std::vector<int> &prev_state, std::vector<int> &curr_state);

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {4, 5};

    a.push_back(3);
    b.push_back(6);
    b.push_back(7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        compute(a, b);
    }
}
```

I would like to determine at compile time if when I call `compute`, the 2 vectors have the same length. For example, the following code should fail at compile time:

```cpp
// A function that modifies the values in the 2 vectors
// But it needs the 2 vectors to have the same length
void compute(std::vector<int> &prev_state, std::vector<int> &curr_state);

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {4, 5};

    a.push_back(3);
    b.push_back(6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        // THIS SHOULD FAIL AT COMPILE TIME BECAUSE a.size() IS 4 AND b.size() IS 5
        compute(a, b);
    }
}
```

I know there is at least a runtime solution for this: adding an if condition that checks the sizes of the vectors. But, if I call the compute times a lot, that might cost me performance.

I know there's a solution with `std::array` instead of `std::vector`:

```cpp
// A function that modifies the values in the 2 vectors
// But it needs the 2 vectors to have the same length
template <size_t N>
void compute(std::array<int, N> &prev_state, std::array<int, N> &curr_state);

int main() {
    std::array<int, 64> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<int, 64> b = {4, 5};

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        compute(a, b);
    }
}
```

But this is too restrictive, as you have to establish the array's length at initialization. And it would generate a different function for every array length for which the function is called. I don't want this. I just want the compiler to check that the lengths are equal when I call compute.

I understand that from just using a `std::vector` it's impossible because there are ways to modify the vector such that we don't know the length at runtime. But we might still be able to determine that 2 vectors have the same length. For example:

```cpp
int main() {
    // Here, we know a.size() is 3
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {4, 5, 6, 7};
    int n;

    std::cin >> n;
    while(n--) {
        a.push_back(n);
        b.push_back(n);
    }
    b.pop();

    // Here, a and b have both length n + 3
    // I would like the compiler to determine that they have the same length
    // Even if it doesn't know n
}
```

I understand that it's a hard problem for the compiler to determine the size of the vector. At least, I want to know is if there are any type hints or features that C++ has that limits the operations that we can do on a vector, such that its length can be determined at compile time.

Tl;DR
My questions are:

1. Given a vector, after applying some operations on it, can the compiler determine its length?
2. If not, is there a way to limit the operations on the vector such that the compiler
   can determine its length?
3. Can the compiler determine if 2 vectors have the same length?
4. Does C++ have any compile time features that can help us check if a relation between two objects holds?

Comment: A `vector`'s data is not allocated until run-time, so you can't check its size at compile-time - UNLESS you are using C++20 or later and declare the `vector` as `constexpr`, that is. But you can't modify a `constexpr vector` after it is constructed.

Comment: No, there's no way. What you want is `assert()` - check this only in debug builds.

Comment: My question is not necessarily about `vector`. It can be about any class.

Comment: It is not possible to determine at compile-time whether the vectors have the same length, because they **do not have a length** at compile-time. The **only** way to know whether `a.size` will be equal to a certain value at a certain point in the execution, is to actually **execute up to that point**. Compile-time calculations require compile-time constants.

Comment: *"question is not necessarily about vector. It can be about any class"* `std::array` can do this, but you already know this. You need to clarify what "any class" is. But generally, you're unlikely to find anything beyond `std::array` and the like.

Comment: "My question is not necessarily about vector. It can be about any class." - and the same reasoning applies to any class. It applies to primitives, too. Which is to say: "Given a vector, after applying some operations on it, can the compiler determine its length?" the compiler cannot possibly do this because **the operations have not happened yet**. Tricks with templated-size `std::array`, with `constexpr` etc. work by **causing** the operations to happen up front. But the **purpose of** a class like std::vector, which allocates memory dynamically, is to figure it out later.

Comment: (After all, a calculation that is forced to happen up front cannot possibly involve user input. It's essentially just a fancier version of constant folding.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, FWIW, you can't declare the vectors `constexpr` either until non-transient allocations are worked out. They're allowed to exist during constant evaluation (as a regularly declared vector within a block of code being run at compile time), but can't escape that context.

Comment: @chris `std::vector` (and `std::string`) was updated in C++20 to allow compile-time usage in `constexpr` contexts.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Perhaps [this example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EWxdecx3o) better shows what I mean. If you try to uncomment the line declaring the vector `constexpr`, the code fails to compile for the reason I mentioned (even if you move the line to the other function), but yes, the type is still usable at compile time as of C++20.

Comment: @MariusPricop: With static analyzer, you might create rule to check that...

Answer (score 1):

Use a single vector.

```
struct states_type
{
   int prev;
   int curr;
};

void compute(std::vector<states_type> &states);

int main() {
    std::vector<states_type> a;

    a.push_back({1,4});
    a.push_back({2,5});
    a.push_back({3,6});

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        compute(a);
    }
}
```